# What is the matrix clause of this?

Tags: relative-clauses

> "I accept there's something strange about you, **probably nothing a
>   good beating wouldn't have cured** –– and as for all this about your
>   parents, well, they were weirdos, no denying it, and the world's
>   better off without them in my opinion - asked for all they got,
>   getting mixed up with these wizarding types - just what I expected,
>   always knew they'd come to a sticky end ––" 
> (Harry Potter and the
>   Sorcerer's Stone)

I suppose the construction might be a preterite perfect. In this case, I wonder what the full matrix clause is supposed to be. I guess it could be ‘**There would have probably been nothing** [a good beating wouldn’t have cured]’. But I’m not sure for I’ve already got one:” "[Your strangeness is nothing [pronoun functioning as subject complement] that (relative pronoun) a good beating wouldn't have cured](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4663/nothing-a-good-beating-wouldnt-have-cured)," which makes me confused. What could be the matrix clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clause in question stands in apposition to the NP which is the complement of *'s* in the previous clause, so it shares its precedent's syntactic role; *nothing* parallels *something*:

> I accept that
>   *there’s*
>       **something** strange about you
>   *it’s*
>     probably **nothing** [which] a good beating wouldn't have cured

ADDED:
The double negative in *nothing which a good beating wouldn’t have cured* is perhaps confusing. Dursley regards Harry’s strangeness as a character flaw which a good beating **would have cured** if it had been administered early enough. In this clause Dursley  rejects the alternative interpretation, that Harry’s strangeness is something innate which a good beating **would not have cured**. *Nothing* here should be understood as *not something*:

> It is not something which a good beating would not have cured.

Comment: If you had said “there’s probably [nothing](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/nothing) [which] a good beating wouldn't have cured”, I wouldn’t have confused. I can’t make out “it(=something strange about you)’s probably~”. Can the double negation make sense with the subject, something strange about you?

Comment: @Listenever - see the addition

Comment: After long old pondering, I started to get some understanding of your explanation. And yours - 'It is not something which a good beating would not have cured' - could be as same as 'It is not anything which a good beating would not have cured', isn't it?

Comment: And yours could be semantically the same as “It is something which a good beating would have cured,” isn’t it?

Comment: @Listenever Exactly. But "nothing" is more dismissive, which is characteristic of that surly fellow.

Comment: As an aside: the layout in the top quote is pretty nice when I look at it on a computer!  On my phone, I couldn't quite figure out what it was saying, I think because it was too wide and wrapped around.  I'm not sure whether or not this is important.

Comment: @snailboat That's interesting to know; I never thought about alternate displays because I don't use a smartphone. ... Must be like the very old days when I worked on a state-of-the-art Osborne 1 with a 5"/52x24-character screen windowed on a 128x32-character display.